# Find all the cycle in a graph including the one with vertex repetition

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a simple graph given by

```
g = 
 Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 5, 
   5 -> 4, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 5, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 6, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 7, 8 -> 1, 
   1 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 8, 9 -> 4, 4 -> 9, 2 -> 9, 9 -> 2, 9 -> 6, 
   6 -> 9}, VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
  VertexSize -> 0.1, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {0, 0}, 2 -> {1, 0}, 3 -> {2, 0}, 
    4 -> {2, -1}, 5 -> {2, -2}, 6 -> {1, -2}, 7 -> {0, -2}, 
    8 -> {0, -1}, 9 -> {1, -1}}]
```

I am looking for all the cycles starting from a specific graph's node with a particular length.

I can obtain a list of all cycles in the graph by using the following command:

```
cycleG = FindCycle[{g, 1}, {4, Infinity}, All];
Grid[Partition[HighlightGraph[g, #] & /@ cycleG, 
  UpTo[4]], Frame -> All]
```

However, by definition, FindCycle finds only cycles where a graph's vertex is not repeated in the loop.

My plan is to classify all the cycles including the one where a vertex is repeated. For this specific example, I can do it by hand, however, I plan to work with more complex graphs.

I have not found a similar problem here. Do you have any idea on how to tackle the problem?

Comment: This approach is not particularly computationally efficient but should be easy to code: the set of vertex repetition-allowed circuits in a graph G is precisely the set of Eulerian cycles in the subgraphs of G that can be induced by sets of cycles in G.

Comment: @DanielMcDonald Thank you for the suggestion; I need to understand your suggestion carefully.

Comment: For a small graph like `g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3,3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4,4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]` the code `Join@@(FindEulerianCycle[#, All] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[Union @@@Subsets[Map[Sort] /@ FindCycle[g, {0, Infinity}, All]]])` will return all vertex repetition-allowed circuits.

Comment: It works for a not-oriented graph, '''\[UndirectedEdge]''', I will try to updated, if possible to '''\[DirectedEdge]'''.

Comment: Remove `Map[Sort]/@` from the code above to make it work for digraphs.